# How to test Google Go binary on ARM?

Tags: testing, go, arm, porting, arm64

Basically, I want to test Google Go compiler binary package on my aarch64 Linux machine. The package was available here:
 https://golang.org/dl/

As the platform is not any OS on x86, I am a bit worried if the binary package would work fine or not. My question is how to test.

I have written a simple GO codes, built them, and ran. So far so good. However, I am not a GO programmer. Thus, I could not be so sure yet that the GO compiler binary package works fine.

If it were not Google GO compiler but GDB for example, I would run make check. If the outcome is not very different from the one that I get on x86, I would be relieved. I do not know what's the preferred way of testing. Any popular test suite?

I do see the test sub directory in the tar ball. What is the sub directory for? If it is testing after porting or so, how do we use it? I could not find documentation in the tarball. I could not find any appropriate texts from Google search either.

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: did you read this https://golang.org/doc/install ?

Comment: Yes, I have read it several times. Nonetheless, I might be missing something. Please, let me know if I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing go from source tests are run to make sure all is well, generally there is no real reason to do this with a binary install. However if you wish to test anyway just run `go test std` to make sure the standard library tests all run fine.

If you are really paranoid you can run `./all.bash` in the go source directory (`user/local/go/src` IIRC) to rebuild from source and run tests on, well, everything. I am not sure how much more (if anything) is actually tested compared to just running the standard library tests though.

Comment: Thank you so much, above all! I would try go test std. 

I believe that it might be worthy testing the binary package on ARM64. Firstly, the official web site seems to say that GO works fine for the platform but maybe not as well as it does for AMD64. Secondly, being distributed in a binary format does not necessarily means working like a magic on my particular platform. Actually, today, the virtualbox binary distribution caused troubles on my PC.

I would agree with you that go test std would be enough. Maybe, besides, I could use the binary as bootstrap to build GO from the source. Thx!